# Regular expression to turn hyphens into double hyphens

Tags: ruby, markdown

My implementation of markdown turns double hyphens into endashes. E.g., **a -- b** becomes **a – b**

But sometimes users write **a - b** when they mean **a -- b**. I'd like a regular expression to fix this.

Obviously `body.gsub(/ - /, " -- ")` comes to mind, but this messes up markdown's unordered lists – i.e., if a line starts `- list item`, it will become `-- list item`. So solution must only swap out hyphens when there is a word character somewhere to their left

Answer (score 1):

You can match a word character to the hyphen's left and use a backreference in the replacement string to put it back:

```
body.gsub(/(\w) - /, '\1 -- ')
```

Comment: you also slap a \s? in there to take care of having space or not:

(\w)\s?-

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, if you want to be a little more accepting ...

```
gsub(/\b([ \t]+)-(?=[ \t]+)/, '\1--')
```

\b[ \t] forces a non-whitepace before the whitespace through a word boundary condition. I don't use \s to avoid line-runs. I also only use one capture to preserve the preceding whitespace (does Ruby 1.8.x have a `?<=` ?).

Comment: What advantage does this regex have over @yjerem's (simpler) answer?

Comment: @Horace It accepts more and preserves input white-space (spaces or tabs). For instance: "Hello\t\t- world!" will be turned into "Hello\t\t-- world!", which may or may not be desirable.